# Problema com CRUD no Java usando Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Na minha classe DAO, tenho o método para inserir no banco de dados, porém na tela do meu sistema eu só consigo atualizar os campos se eu fizer uma mudança em todos os campos.

Exemplo: minha tabela tem 4 campos e eu só modifico 1, o update não funciona pelo meu botão, mas se eu modificar o texto dos 4 campos o update funciona.

Método da classe DAO para atualizar campo:

```
public boolean alterar(Cidades cidades)
{
String sql = “UPDATE tb_cidade SET nome_Cidade = ?, tb_estado_id_Estado = ? WHERE id_Cidade = ?”;
try
{
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, cidades.getNome_Cidades());
stmt.setInt(2, cidades.getId_Estados());
stmt.setInt(3, cidades.getId_Cidades());

        stmt.execute();

        return true;
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível alterar do banco: " + ex);
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Método da Classe Controller que chama o método alterar da classe DAO:

```
@FXML
private void atualizarDadosSelecionados(ActionEvent event) {

    Cidades cidades = new Cidades();

    cidades.setNome_Cidades(txtNomeCidade.getText());
    cidades.setId_Estados(comboBoxSiglaEstado.getValue().getId_Estado());
    cidades.setId_Cidades(Integer.parseInt(txtCodigoCidade.getText()));


    cidadesDAO.alterar(cidades);

    carregaCidadesNaTableView();

    limparCampos();

}
```

Comment: Se vc esta querendo modificar só um campo, por que tem dois campos na sua consulta???

Comment: Boa noite, campos notnull precisam ser preenchidos mesmo que com nada.